# How to automate the renaming of the index in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have found 2 methods to rename the index in Pandas dataframe. But both are not practical when the dataframe is very big.

How can I automate the renaming?

Method 1:

```
df=df.rename(index={0: 's1', 1: 's2', 2: 's3', 3: 's4', 4: 's5'})
```

Method 2:

```
df['new_index']=['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5']
df=df.set_index('new_index')
```

I have tried this:

```
df=df.rename(index={'s_' + ind for ind in range(1, len(df.index)+1)})
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehension` with cast `int` to `str`:

```
df.index = ['s_' + str(ind) for ind in range(1, len(df.index)+1)]
```

because you can use assign:

```
df.index=['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5'] 
print (df)
    A
s1  1
s2  2
s3  3
s4  4
s5  5
```

Another simplier solution - concanecate `s_` with added `1` to `index` and casted to `str`:

```
df.index = 's_' + (df.index + 1).astype(str)
print (df)
     A
s_1  1
s_2  2
s_3  3
s_4  4
s_5  5
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(5)})
print (df)
   A
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4

df.index = ['s_' + str(ind) for ind in range(1, len(df.index)+1)]
print (df)
     A
s_1  0
s_2  1
s_3  2
s_4  3
s_5  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a lambda function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2))

df
Out: 
          0         1
0 -0.473776  0.211539
1 -2.763357  1.555551
2  0.157333  0.116125
3 -1.069105  0.319615
4 -0.560871  0.572320

df.rename(index=lambda x: "s{}".format(x+1))
Out: 
           0         1
s1 -0.473776  0.211539
s2 -2.763357  1.555551
s3  0.157333  0.116125
s4 -1.069105  0.319615
s5 -0.560871  0.572320
```